# How to view multiple vr scenes on one page?

Tags: javascript, html, virtual-reality, aframe

I'm trying to view multiple 360 photos using the *a-frame* library by implementing *a-scene*. 
but only one scene is rendered on my page. Is there any workaround to solve this?

Is there is any other library to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If You want to have many scenes on one screen, You would need to embed them into a couple of div's and place them as You wish.
The code looks like this:

```
a-scene {
  height: 300px;
  width: 600px;
}
<body>
  <div id="myEmbeddedScene">
    <a-scene embedded>
      <!-- ... -->
    </a-scene>
  </div>
</body>
```

Multiple scenes may need embedding them in iframes, as explained in the [docs](https://aframe.io/docs/0.6.0/components/embedded.html).
If You want to switch between scenes, You can make their visible attribute true or false.